# Wordpress tiny mce editor does not show exact in the front end

Tags: wordpress

I recently started developing websites on wordpress. I have this problem with tinymce editor. When i write post and format content it looks how I want in it. But when I publish post and check that it looks really crappy.Then I called the stylesheet of tinymce editor on everypage of website. I must say there is change but it still looks bad.

How can I get content in exact formatted way as I see in the tinyMCE?

Thanks,

kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the frontend the styles from your theme will be taking precedence over the layout and sizing of content.

In the administration section it will be using a default TinyMCE editor css file. This allows for Wordpress to easily support a variety of themes without making many changes.

So that leaves you with the potential inconsistency, which you have identified here.

Either you work with the WYSIWYG editor giving you an approximation or you could add the relevant styles from your theme to the editors CSS. This can be done using [`add_editor_style()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style).

Answer (score -1):

Use this WordPress plugin to solve your problem.

[Specific CSS/JS for Posts and Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/specific-cssjs-for-posts-and-pages/)

Comment: That plugin solves an entirely different problem and is not really suitable as answer to the original question.

Comment: To add your stylesheet to the TinyMCE editor just add this as a filter. you can do this in your functions.php file.

/*
 *
 *  Adds a filter to append the default stylesheet to the tinymce editor.
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists('tdav_css') ) {
 function tdav_css($wp) {
  $wp .= ',' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url');
 return $wp;
 }
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'tdav_css' );

Comment: No, you would use the Wordpress function `add_editor_style()` as mentioned in my answer.